# Edge browser caret positioning on touch device

Tags: javascript, touch, microsoft-edge, virtual-keyboard

I'm working on a web app which uses [simple-keyboard](https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard) javascript library.

By looking at the source code, I can see that the library synchronizes its internal keyboard buffer and caret position with the input field's ones by executing some sync code (selectionStart) on certain events: keyup, mouseup, touchend.

https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard/blob/master/src/lib/components/Keyboard.js#L574

On a touch device and only in Edge browser, there is an issue with it. The problem is that Edge doesn't seem to allow placing the caret by clicking somewhere within the bounds of the text, but allows the user to *drag the caret cursor*.

**This 'dragging' doesn't seem to fire touchend event**, so the input's cursor and virtual keyboard caret go out of sync.

Does anyone know if I can prevent this dragging behaviour in Edge (and allow positioning within the text with a simple touch) or if there is some Edge specific event for dragging the cursor?

**Example:**

```js
/**
 * This seems to work in any browser **Except** on a touch device in Edge browser
 */
document.addEventListener("keyup", caretEventHandler);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", caretEventHandler);
document.addEventListener("touchend", caretEventHandler);

function caretEventHandler(event) {
  let targetTagName;
  if (event.target.tagName) {
    targetTagName = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
  }

  if (targetTagName === "textarea" || targetTagName === "input") {
    document.querySelector(".selectionStart span").innerHTML =
      event.target.selectionStart;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.selectionStart {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input
      class="input"
      value="Click anywhere in this string to get selectionStart"
    />
    <div class="selectionStart">selectionStart: <span></span></div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to your code and the github's demo code, I've made a test on my side, and the code seems work well on Edge. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsPIW.gif  Could you please show your issue with a screenshot?

Comment: @JeniferJiang , that doesn't seem like a touch device ...

Comment: I've also test your code on my phone,it seems not appearing your issue. Which kind of device you use?

Comment: Hello @JeniferJiang, I was able to reproduce this on a Windows 10 laptop, Edge browser and using the laptop's touch screen. Here's a screenshot + more info: https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard/issues/54#issuecomment-466733511
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a solution for this yet. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @pevgeniev hi, I'm sorry that I forget to ask that on your laptop when you touch if there is any information in your developer tool's console tab. And which Edge version do you use? Maybe this will affect.